# Get data from HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I'm sending an HTTP GET request from the client to my server. On the server, I can't access the data that is passed with the GET request. It works for POST requests but the value is not received in the get request.

The client is Vue.js, and the Server is Express.js in Node.js. The code looks like this.

**Client:**

```
var response = await axios.get('/endpoint',{ key: 'value' });
```

**Server:**

```
router.get('/endpoint', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // empty
    console.log(req.query);  // empty
    console.log(req.params); // empty
});
```

I've set up my `body-parser` above. It looks like below

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyparser.json() );
```

How do I access the {key: 'value'} object that is sent from the client in my server.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body. To send data, you need to use `var response = axios.get('/endpoint?key1=value1&key2=value2');`

Comment: Why do you console log 'req.body' and not just req.body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Axios you can path query params to GET call in 2 different ways:

1. By putting them into the endpoint path

`await axios.get('/endpoint?key=value&key2=value2');`

2. Add them to the config argument in `params` property object as key-value

`await axios.get('/endpoint', { params: {key: 'value', key2: 'value2' }});`

Your confusion absolutely makes sense, you try to use same way to pass param for get and post methods, but in Axios these methods have different number of arguments: post(url, data, config), get(url, config)

Let's return to your example:
`var response = await axios.get('/endpoint',{ key: 'value' });`

So now you can see that `{ key: 'value' }` object that you pass as a second argument is request config and isn't a data.

You can learn more about request config params here - https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Answer (score 3):

GET requests do not have bodies

Comment: Then how to send the data and how can i access the data in the server?

Comment: There are many ways. Watch this https://youtu.be/iYM2zFP3Zn0

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you want to access body by

```
console.log('req.body');
```

instead of

```
console.log(req.body);
```

Also, as pointed above, GET doesn't have body.

Comment: Sorry. Typing mistake while I typed in here.

Comment: @SivaChandran Sure! Hope that helped! Also, in this community, it is a good behavior to upvote and accepts the answer that you liked. I would appreciate it if you upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. But I made that mistake while I was manually hard typing the question in Stack Overflow. Your answer didn't solve my problem instead it helped me correct my question here. So thanks for it and I'm upvoting your answer. The correct answer to my question is below.